# Using Fast-Endpoints how can I set the location header to use path params instead of query params in a 201 response?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, fast-endpoints

Looking at the documentation I only found this usage example:

```
await SendCreatedAtAsync<GetUser.Endpoint>(new { id = response.Id}, response);
```

This produces a 201 response and the location header is set to something like:

> "api/foo/bars?id="12345"

I would like that the location header was something like this:

```
"api/foo/bars/12345"
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm unable to reproduce your issue with the following:

**User Create Endpoint**

```cs
public class Endpoint : EndpointWithoutRequest
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Post("api/user/create");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken c)
    {
        var response = "user created!";
        await SendCreatedAtAsync<GetUserEndpoint>(new { id = 101 }, response);
    }
}
```

**User Get Endpoint**

```cs
public class GetUserEndpoint : EndpointWithoutRequest<GetUserResponse>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Get("/api/user/{id}");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return SendAsync(new()
        {
            Id = Route<int>("id"),
            Name = "Test"
        });
    }
}
```

i see the correct url in the response header like so:

[image]

i'm assuming your anonymous object which is passed in to `SendCreatedAtAsync` might not be correctly matching with the route param of the `GetUserEndpoint`.

if that's not the case, show me how to replicate the problem.